# Returns all values from all columns in a list (CSOM)

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, csom

I'm stuck to something probably very basics

So the idea is the following:
I have a list with 4 columns : *Title*, *CostCenter*, *City*, *currency*

Via CSOM, I'd like to read this list, so I did something like that:

```
ClientContext SPcontext = new ClientContext("MySharepointsite");
         Web web = SPcontext.Web;

         List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListTest");
         CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
         ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
         SPcontext.Load(list);
         SPcontext.Load(items);
         SPcontext.ExecuteQuery();

         foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
         {

              Console.Writeline(FieldName = listItem["Title"].ToString());
              Console.Writeline(listItem["City"].ToString());

         }
```

But it returns me the following error message:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException:
>   'The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been
>   requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be
>   explicitly requested.'

I know that it's comming from my line:

```
Console.Writeline(listItem["City"].ToString());
```

because I remove it, it works

Any idea of how could I do that?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this line:

```
SPcontext.Load(items);
```

with this:

```
SPcontext.Load(items, its => its.Include(item => item["currency"], item => item["Title"], item => item["CostCenter"], item => item["City"]));
```

That way you are asking for specific columns to be downloaded from server.

Answer (score 0):

Since City is not a default list field, you will have to specifically include it in your `load` call.
Title, CostCenter, City, currency

```
SPcontext.Load(items, items => items.include(item => item["Title"], item => item["City"], item => item["CostCenter"], item => item["currency"]));
```

Any time custom columns are being retrieved, they have to be specifically asked for.

as a template

```
SPcontext.Load(<ItemCollection>, <Variable for item collection> => <variable for item collection>.include(<variable for item> => <variable for item>["<field name"], <variable for item> => <variable for item>["<field name"]));
```

FOR EXAMPLE

```
SPcontext.Load(itemCollection, col => col.include(i => i["Title"], i => i["Description"]));
```